# Changing SAS EG project from local server to sas app server

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Is there a way to change my SAS enterprise guide project from running local to run on my sas app server, without making the a new project from the beginning?

Comment: What do you mean with local? Do you have also sas base installed locally? Or are you simply opening a local file but you have a server based installation? Could you clarify a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SAS EG, open "Tools" then "Project Maintenance". You can replace all references to your local server with a new server as well as related assets such as librefs, datasets.

We used this little wizard a lot when we did a migration of our site. Works like a charm.

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: Hey @JannickMikkelsen  I am glad that I could help. Thank you for accepting my asnwer.